# Name error: Name "server" not defined Python

Tags: python, tcp

Hola tengo una versión de `Python 2.7` y en este momento no se porque me devuelve este error a la hora de configurar un servidor TCP.

> server = server.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>   NameError: name 'server' is not defined

El código es:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"
bind_port = 9999

server = server.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port))

def handle_client(client_socket):

    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print("[*] Receivd: %s" % request)

    client_socket.send("ACK!")
    client_socket.close()

    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print("[*] Accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, ))
        client_handler.start()
```

Espero que sus respuesta me sean de gran ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que cambiar server por socket aquí:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

El script completo escuchando en localhost:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)

def handle_client(client_socket):

    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print "[*] Receivd: %s" % request

    client_socket.send("ACK!")

    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print("[*] Accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, ))
    client_handler.start()
```

El error 99 es **EADDRNOTAVAIL** que indica que estas intentando escuchar en una dirección ip no disponible, usa la correcta o localhost.

Comment: Ahora cuando intento ejecutar pasa esto

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dp11ga

Comment: Arreglado ya esta